# Can't determine the exact sonarqube issue here

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have following API end point. this is the part of my code.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("alert/SMS")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendSMS(SendSMSReq req)
{
    try
    {
        CHeader cHeader = new CHeader
        {
            uuid = Request.Headers["uuid"],
            channel = Request.Headers["channel"]
        };

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.mobileNo) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.message))
        {
            APILog.LogInformation(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, cHeader.uuid, "Mobile no or Null request received");
            var errorMsg001 = await Translation.Translation.GetRedisCache(cHeader.uuid, "core.alert.001", cHeader.channel);
            string message = errorMsg001.messageCode != "001" && errorMsg001.messageCode != "999999" ? errorMsg001.messageText : "Invalid Mobile Number or Message";
            return BadRequest(message);
        }

        var result = await sendSMSRepository.SendSMS(req, cHeader);
        
        if(result.status == "001")
        {
            var errorMsg001 = await Translation.Translation.GetRedisCache(cHeader.uuid, "core.alert.001", cHeader.channel);
            result.message = errorMsg001.messageCode != "001" && errorMsg001.messageCode != "999999" ? errorMsg001.messageText : "Invalid Mobile Number or Message";
            return BadRequest(result);
        }
        if (result == null)
        {
            APILog.LogInformation(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, cHeader.uuid, "Mobile no or Null request received");
            var errorMsg001 = await Translation.Translation.GetRedisCache(cHeader.uuid, "core.alert.002", cHeader.channel);
            result.message = errorMsg001.messageCode != "001" && errorMsg001.messageCode != "999999" ? errorMsg001.messageText : "Error occurred, please try again after few minutes";
            return NotFound("Error occurred, please try again after few minutes");
        }

        return Accepted(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        APILog.LogError(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.Name, req?.mobileNo, ex, "Exception");
        
        return NotFound("Error occurred, please try again after few minutes");
    }
   
}
```

In the above code, Sonarqube showing major bus in this line.

```
    if (result == null)
    {
        APILog.LogInformation(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, cHeader.uuid, "Mobile no or Null request received");
        var errorMsg001 = await Translation.Translation.GetRedisCache(cHeader.uuid, "core.alert.002", cHeader.channel);
        result.message = errorMsg001.messageCode != "001" && errorMsg001.messageCode != "999999" ? errorMsg001.messageText : "Error occurred, please try again after few minutes";
        return NotFound("Error occurred, please try again after few minutes");
    }
```

Is shows, following error message.

**`Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed.`**

What's wrong here, someone please explain me to resolve this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if(result.status == "001")
        {
            // ...
        }
        if (result == null)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

I guess if `result` was really `null`, your code would blow up already at `result.status`, and hence would never reach the last `if`.

You could change the order of the `if`s. Or you could say `result?.status` instead (null-safe).

Comment: Yeah, I got the point, thank u :)

Comment: @NAKED_DEVELOPER In your defense, sometimes the cause of a SonarQube error is not immediately obvious and can sometimes be quite elusive.